# Save a file with Filename while saving the content Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create and save the file in Drive starting 01 , but if I rename the file , it changes the file type . Here is the code I am using

```
function saveInDriveFolder( url , foldername, j){
  var curfol = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername).next()
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , { muteHttpExceptions: true })
  if( file.getResponseCode() == 200 ) { 
  curfol.createFile(file);
  }
}
```

I have tried

```
curfol.createFile(j,file);
```

but this loses the file type, then I have changed this to

```
curfol.createFile(j + ".jpg", file);
```

This is not working.

I am trying to save images starting from 01.jpg

Comment: I don't know the file format/content of the file coming in from the external source.  `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url ,options)` returns an HTTPResponse.  You will probably need to use `getAs()` on the return value:  [Link to Apps Script Docs getAs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getAs(String))   `file = file.getAs('image/jpeg')`  Add that line after, or chain getAs() to the end of existing statement.

Comment: The file coming from the external source is .jpg. I want to rename the file while saving

Comment: Okay, I should have know that it was jpeg.  But that doesn't matter.  You need to use another method on the HTTPReponse that is returned from UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).

Answer (score 0):

`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` returns a response object, not the raw jpeg, this is why you can use the `getResponseCode()` to check if you received an HTTP 200 response or not.

You need to use `getAs(MimeType.JPEG)` or `getBlob()` to get the contents of the file

So your code which creates the file should look something like this:

`curFol.createFile('01.jpg', file.getAs(MimeType.JPEG));`

See:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename-content-mimetype

Comment: Whenever I use this curFol.createFile('01.jpg', file.getAs(MimeType.JPEG), MimeType.JPEG); the file content is lost. The jpg file opens with a X in middle

Comment: curfol.createFile(file); worked , but I cannot rename the file

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this the code changes is as below :

```
function saveInDriveFolder( url , foldername, j){
  var curfol = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername).next()
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , { muteHttpExceptions: true })
  if( file.getResponseCode() == 200 ) { 
    k = j > 9 ? "" + j: "0" + j
  var blob = file.getBlob().setName( k + '.jpg');
  curfol.createFile(blob);

  }
}
```